# How to set up the JavaEE First Cup tutorial in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm going through the tutorial (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/firstcup/creating-example002.htm). I have Eclipse for EE developers (4.6.3) with Glassfish (4.x) properly configured in it.

I see the project folder under `glassfish4\docs\firstcup` but I don't know how to import it since the instructions are for Netbeans. If I try to "Open projects from file system" or a general import I get just the folder structure in the workspace and not with the right "flavor":

[image]

Then Glassfish doesn't recognize this as a resource that can be added. How do I do this in Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck with the same problem.

Here are the steps I took to make it work.

1. Skip the step where you have to open the `firstcup` project and build.
2. When you have to create the `dukes-age` project and the `firstcup-war` project, go to File > New > Maven Project.
3. Make sure the "Create a simple project (skip archetype selection)" option is unchecked. Click Next.
4. On the next page, you have to select an archetype. Choose "All Catalogs" and type `glassfish` in Filter and you will see the 2 archetypes you need for the tutorial.
   [image: select an archetype]
5. On the next page, you need to enter Group Id and Artifact Id. For the `dukes-age` project, type `firstcup.dukesage.resource` in Group Id and `dukes-age` for Artifact Id. Click Finish.
6. You will notice that there's an error in your pom.xml file. Open it and edit by removing `-SNAPSHOT` from the line `<version>8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`. Save.
7. Right click the project in Project Explorer (the left pane). Go to Maven > Update Project.
8. Skip the step to set the default URL for dukes-age. Instead, when you want to test your completed web service, go to `http://localhost:8080/dukes-age/webapi/dukesAge/`.

Note for the `firstcup-war` project. Before adding the project to the server, make sure you start Derby by running `./asadmin start-database` inside `glassfish5/bin`. Otherwise, you have to remove the project from the server and add it back.

That's all. Other than that, everything is quite similar to the steps in the tutorial. Feel free to ask.

Comment: oh em gee thanks for this, it even says to add `/webapi/dukesAge` in the Relative URL field and I did that, but after running the app at that point it was gone